# OpenCV: Storing the coordinates of the points clicked by mouse left button

Tags: c++, opencv

The following program would give the location of left mouse button click.

```
 void onMouse(int evt, int x, int y, int flags, void* param) {
    if(evt == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN) {
        cv::Point* ptPtr = (cv::Point*)param;
        ptPtr->x = x;
        ptPtr->y = y;
    }
}

int main() {
    cv::Point2i pt(-1,-1);//assume initial point
    cv::namedWindow("Output Window");

    Mat frame = cv::imread("chhhha.png");

    cv::setMouseCallback("Output Window", onMouse, (void*)&pt);
   int X, Y; 

    while(1)
    {
    cv::imshow("Output Window", frame);

    X=pt.x; 

    Y=pt.y; 

    cout<<"X and Y coordinates are given below"<<endl;
   cout<<X<<'\t'<<Y<<endl; 


 waitKey(10);

    }


    getch(); 
}
```

I want to draw a line connecting the two points user clicks. I know line can be drawn by the function:

```
C++: void line(Mat& img, Point pt1, Point pt2, const Scalar& color, int thickness=1, int lineType=8, int shift=0)
```

But the problem is I have to provide two points to this function, but my previous point is lost as can be seen in the following code:

```
   void onMouse(int evt, int x, int y, int flags, void* param) {
        if(evt == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN) {
            cv::Point* ptPtr = (cv::Point*)param;
            ptPtr->x = x;
            ptPtr->y = y;
        }
    }

    int main() {
        cv::Point2i pt(-1,-1);
        cv::namedWindow("Output Window");

        Mat frame = cv::imread("chhhha.png");

        cv::setMouseCallback("Output Window", onMouse, (void*)&pt);
       int X, Y; 

        while(1)
        {
        cv::imshow("Output Window", frame);

        X=pt.x; 

        Y=pt.y; 

        cout<<"X and Y coordinates are given below"<<endl;
       cout<<X<<'\t'<<Y<<endl; 



 line(frame,  pt1,  pt2, 'r',  1,  8,  0); //here I am having only one point. This is the issue  


     waitKey(10);

        }


        getch(); 
    }
```

**Edit**

So is there anyway to store the coordinates of the point clicked by user. So let's say user clicks two points on the image, and we would store x coordinates of the two clicks in X[0] and X[1], and similarly Y[0] and Y[1] for y coordinates.

Then I can easily use the function for drawing a line.  Kindly help me proceed in this direction.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

**My latest code**

```
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


void onMouse(int evt, int x, int y, int flags, void* param) {
    if(evt == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN) {
        std::vector<cv::Point>* ptPtr = (std::vector<cv::Point>*)param;
        ptPtr->push_back(cv::Point(x,y));
    }
}

int main()

{
std::vector<Point> points;

cv::namedWindow("Output Window");

Mat frame = cv::imread("chhha.png");

cv::setMouseCallback("Output Window", onMouse, (void*)&points);
int X=0, Y=0; 


while(1)
{
    cv::imshow("Output Window", frame);

X=points[0].x; 
Y=points[0].y; 

cout<<"First X and Y coordinates are given below"<<endl;
cout<<X<<'\t'<<Y<<endl; 


    waitKey(10);
}


getch(); 

}
```

**This has two major issues:**

1- This would compile well, but during run time it gives `Debug Assertion Failed!` error,

at the following lines when I debugged by putting breakpoints:

```
X=points[0].x; 
Y=points[0].y;
```

It further says:

> Expression: Vector subscript out of range

2- How do I come out of the while loop? 
In other similar programs I noticed that it remains in while loop forever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest that instead of passing to a `cv::Point*`, pass a `std::vector<cv::Point>*`. Since `cv::Point` has a copy constructor, you can store points in there by `push_back`.

The code as I mean it:

```
std::vector<cv:Point> points;
cv::namedWindow("Output Window");

Mat frame = cv::imread("chhhha.png");

cv::setMouseCallback("Output Window", onMouse, (void*)&points);
int X, Y; 

while(1)
{
    cv::imshow("Output Window", frame);

    if (points.size() > 2) //we have 2 points
    {
        for (auto it = points.begin(); it != points.end(); ++it)
        {

            cout<<"X and Y coordinates are given below"<<endl;
            cout<<(*it).x<<'\t'<<(*it).y<<endl; 
        }
        //draw points
    }
...
```

and in the callback:

```
void onMouse(int evt, int x, int y, int flags, void* param) {
    if(evt == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN) {
        std::vector<cv::Point>* ptPtr = (std::vector<cv::Point>*)param;
        ptPtr->push_back(cv::Point(x,y));
    }
}
```

Later on, you can access the first 2 points with `points[0]` and `points[1]`.

EDIT: updated the code with a check of the vector size. You should note that this method might require locking, if the mouse callback is executed in a different thread.

Comment: Greatttt it worked!! The only thing is now can I  store these values and access outside the while loop . something like this: X1=points[0].x; X2=points[1].x and so on. This is my main difficulty.

Comment: you can do exactly that! give it a try. Just keep in mind you have to make sure you have enough points. For example, run the while loop until `points.size() > 2`, and then `break`. Then you can access.

Comment: I think I am about make it work.  But Still I am stuck within the while loop. how do i exit the while loop, and go back to console and print my values?

Comment: I put a break; in for loop. and it worked fine. Thanks (there is a small issue, it hangs if I 'not reponding error' after some time, thsi I will ask in another question. many thanks for your help)